# Input Range value updating on double clicks instead of single click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have created an input of type range using react with typescript. The problem I am facing is when I click on the increase/decrease button I have to click them twice then it will increase/decrease value. Sometimes when the value becomes a hundred the decrease button stop working.

Here is the code:

```
export default function App() {
  const rangeRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const [rangeValue, setRangeValue] = useState<number>(0);

  const updateRangeValue = () => {
    const rangeRefference = rangeRef.current;
    if (rangeRefference) {
      const currentSilderLevel: number = (rangeRefference.value as unknown) as number;
      setRangeValue(currentSilderLevel);
    }
  };

  const increaseValue = () => {
    const sliderValue = rangeValue + 10;
    setRangeValue(sliderValue);
  };

  const decreaseValue = () => {
    const sliderValue = rangeValue - 10;
    setRangeValue(sliderValue);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={decreaseValue}>Decrease</button>
      <input
        type="range"
        min="0"
        max="100"
        step="10"
        onChange={updateRangeValue}
        value={rangeValue}
        ref={rangeRef}
      />
      <button onClick={increaseValue}>Increase</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I also created a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-cbfxvi?file=/src/App.tsx:66-1026) sandbox

Comment: `step="20"` Would the `input` value change just for the increment of 10?
Wouldn't it be 10 for `step` too?

Comment: That's my bad it's a typo error. But the issue still persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this happens because your rangerValue goes beyond your 0-100 limit.
and also you do not need to use refs for this. just use useState hook.

I have refactored your code.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [rangeValue, setRangeValue] = useState<number>(0);

  const increaseValue = () => {
    let sliderValue = Math.min(rangeValue + 10, 100);
    setRangeValue(sliderValue);
  };

  const decreaseValue = () => {
    let sliderValue = Math.max(0, rangeValue - 10);
    setRangeValue(sliderValue);
  };

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent) => {
    const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement
    setRangeValue(parseInt(target.value, 10))
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={decreaseValue}>Decrease</button>
      <input
        type="range"
        min="0"
        max="100"
        step="10"
        value={rangeValue}
        onChange = {handleChange}
      />
      <button onClick={increaseValue}>Increase</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

check it out!

[image: Edit red-cloud-ljg4ut]

Comment: do I need to add onChange event to get the value if slider scrolled using thumb

Comment: yes, you need to add onChange event handler function and inside that function, you can update the state.

Comment: Did you check my way?

I am using ref but here you mentioned that no need to use ref

Comment: updated the answer. check it out.

Comment: you can find value from the event object passed to the handler function. so you don't need to use refs here.

Answer (score 1):

Check this part of code.

```
const increaseValue = () => {
  const sliderValue = rangeValue + 10;
  setRangeValue(sliderValue);
};

const decreaseValue = () => {
  const sliderValue = rangeValue - 10;
  setRangeValue(sliderValue);
};
```

What happens when you click more than ten times, the `sliderValue` will become more than 100 and that won't appear on `input` tag. Same with decrement also.

I just added a condition for increment and decrement like this.

```
const increaseValue = () => {
  const sliderValue = rangeValue + 10;
  setRangeValue(sliderValue > 100 ? 100 : sliderValue);
};

const decreaseValue = () => {
  const sliderValue = rangeValue - 10;
  setRangeValue(sliderValue < 0 ? 0 : sliderValue);
};
```

I am attaching a sandbox for reference.

[image: Edit React Typescript (forked)]

Answer (score 0):

What about setting the state like this ?

```
setRangeValue(prev => prev + 10);
```

Ok I got it, you have put this props step="20" on your input, change it to step="10"

Comment: That's my bad it's a typo error. But the issue still persists

Comment: Really ? The sandBox works fine for me

Comment: take the slider on right end then try decrease button